# Create alias for ID

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website based on FoodHunt Theme by ThemeGrill (free version - demo [HERE](https://demo.themegrill.com/demos/?theme=FoodHunt)). The homepage is created based on widgets as you can see:

[image]

Each widget has a unique ID (#foodhunt_service_widget-2, #foodhunt_service_widget-3 and so on). I don't think it's possible (or recommended) to change a widget ID.

I need to create a menu with anchors for each widget session. However, I don't want the link to be "#foodhunt_service_widget-2", but "quem-somos" and so on.

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an alias for these widget IDs, so I can use the alias on the menu links and the page will still scroll to the widget areas. The main purpose is to show beautiful anchor links on the menu, not letting the user know that the section is called "foodhunt_service_widget-2" and so on.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Although I'm working with WordPress, this is a coding question and I thought it would be suitable for StackOverflow. If this is not appropriate, please let me know.

Comment: the short answer, you cannot ... but you may create a whole system using JS, your use the ID's you want (the aliases) and on click you match them with the real one and you make the smooth scroll. Since it's a wordpress site you can easily code this as a plugin or include the jQuery code directly within the site

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Is this JS piece complicated? Can you give me a hand? I'm not very familiar with JS. Also, if you think there is another way of "hiding the ugly anchors" from the visitor, I'd appreciate your thoughts. Thank you!